# I need to do a sub-query to list out the different employees (include name, email, birthday) who are working and have multiple skills,

Tags: database, oracle

I have the following tables:

Table EMPLOYEE:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
EmpNo number CONSTRAINT PK_EmpNo PRIMARY KEY ,
EmpName varchar2(30),
Birthday DATE not null,
DeptNo number,
MgrNo varchar2(30) not null,
StartDate DATE not null,
Salary number(7,2) not null,
SYS_Level int,
Status int,
CONSTRAINT ck_SYS_Level CHECK  (SYS_Level > 0 AND SYS_Level < 8), 
CONSTRAINT ck_Status CHECK (Status >= 0 AND Status <= 2), 
Note varchar2(4000)
```

TABLE SKILL:

```
CREATE TABLE SKILL(
SkillNo int not null,
SkillName varchar(30) not null, 
Note varchar2(4000),
CONSTRAINT PK_SkillNo PRIMARY KEY(SkillNo)
```

TABLE EMP_SKILL:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_SKILL(
SkillNo int not null,
EmpNo number not null,
SkillLevel int CONSTRAINT CK_SkillLevel CHECK (SkillLevel >= 1 and SkillLevel<=3) ,
RegDate DATE not null,
Description varchar2(4000),
CONSTRAINT FK_SkillNo FOREIGN KEY(SkillNo) REFERENCES SKILL(SkillNo),
CONSTRAINT FK_EmpNo FOREIGN KEY(EmpNo) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmpNo)
```

Here is what Im trying to do, Status = 0 mean still working:

```
SELECT E.EmpName, E.Email, E.Birthday, S.SkillName
FROM (EMPLOYEE E  JOIN EMP_Skill M ON E.EmpNo = M.EmpNo) JOIN SKILL S ON M.SkillNo = S.SkillNo   
WHERE Status = 0 AND S.SkillName = '.NET'
```

The problem is I think what Im trying to do is not like a SUB-QUERY technique. Sorry if I did something wrong to the code. Any suggestions? Tks.

Comment: You want to find out employees with multiple skills, but then you include ```S.SkillName = '.NET'``` in the where clause, do you mean employees with multiple skills should have one of their skills to be '.NET'?

Comment: yes, that is what Im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5583e404948970a5964b7400751179a9):

Option 1 : If you need employee details and skillname then :

```
WITH TMP1 AS (
SELECT m.empno
FROM emp_skill m
JOIN skill s ON m.skillno = s.skillno
WHERE s.skillname = '.NET'
),
TMP2 AS (
SELECT empno
FROM emp_skill 
GROUP BY empno
HAVING COUNT(skillno) >=2
)

SELECT e.empname, e.email, e.birthday, s.skillname
FROM employee e
JOIN emp_skill m ON e.empno = m.empno
JOIN skill s ON m.skillno = s.skillno
JOIN TMP1 ON e.empno = TMP1.empno
JOIN TMP2 ON e.empno = TMP2.empno
WHERE e.status = 0;
```

Option 2 : If you only need employee details then:

```
WITH TMP1 AS (
SELECT m.empno
FROM emp_skill m
JOIN skill s ON m.skillno = s.skillno
WHERE s.skillname = '.NET'
)

SELECT e.empname, e.email, e.birthday
FROM employee e
JOIN emp_skill m ON e.empno = m.empno
JOIN skill s ON m.skillno = s.skillno
JOIN TMP1 ON e.empno = TMP1.empno
WHERE e.status = 0
GROUP BY e.empname, e.email, e.birthday
HAVING COUNT(s.skillno) >= 2;
```

Comment: I have followed ur instruction but it say table or view does not exist thought... Im following option[1].

Comment: @AnnaLily did you mispell the table names "tmp1" "tmp2"

Comment: ahh sorry, but i dunno what is TMP1-2 mean? can u explain for me that?

Comment: Basically it is a temporary table and is similar to subquery. You can look up more on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html#:~:text=A%20common%20table%20expression%20(CTE,that%20statement%2C%20possibly%20multiple%20times.